# before or after within variable window?

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I am trying to design a rule system where the rules themselves can be external configured, using a rule configuration object. Specifically, I want to configure externally to the DRL rule definition what the minimum time between rule firings for a particular type of rule should be.

My approach so far is to insert the rule configuration as a fact ValueRuleSpec:

```
rule "Any value detected"
when
    $r : ValueRuleSpec(mode == ValueRuleSpecMode.ANY(), $devices: devices)
    $e : SensorEvent(deviceId memberOf $devices) from entry-point FMSensorEvents
    not Activation(ruleSpec == $r, cause == $e)
then
    insert(new Activation($r, $e));
end
```

The $r ValueRuleSpec object has a property *triggerEvery* that contains the minimum number of seconds between activations. I know that this can be done statically by testing for the absence of an Activation object that is inside a specific range before $e using something like:

```
not Activation(this before[60s, 0s] $e)
```

How could I do this with a configurable time window, using the $r.triggerEvery property as the number of seconds?

Comment: The temporal operators, i.e., `before`, `after`, etc., are just syntactic sugar for certain conditions involving the timestamps of the events referenced in a temporal expression. (You'll find the definitions of the operators in the Drools manual.) Writing a DRL function of static method that computes the same relation while including parameters coming from a third fact should not be too difficult. You may need to have the timestamp as a field in the event, set by Java code when the event is inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question based on the advice of laune.

The before keyword's behavior is [described in the manual](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch09.html#d0e13104) as:

> ```
> $eventA : EventA( this before[ 3m30s, 4m ] $eventB )
> ```
>
> The previous pattern will match if and only if the temporal distance
>   between the time when $eventA finished and the time when $eventB
>   started is between ( 3 minutes and 30 seconds ) and ( 4 minutes ). In
>   other words:
>
> ```
> 3m30s <= $eventB.startTimestamp - $eventA.endTimeStamp <= 4m
> ```

Looking up the [source code for the before evaluator](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/f7ab4ee3c88d767a8cbb372c2db1afa84b20a51d/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/base/evaluators/BeforeEvaluatorDefinition.java#L246) we can see the same.

```
 @Override
 protected boolean evaluate(long rightTS, long leftTS) {
     long dist = leftTS - rightTS;
     return this.getOperator().isNegated() ^ (dist >= this.initRange && dist <= this.finalRange);
 }
```

Based on this I've modified my code accordingly, and it seems to work correctly now:

```
rule "Any value detected"
when
    $r : ValueRuleSpec(mode == ValueRuleSpecMode.ANY(), $devices: devices)
    $e : SensorEvent(deviceId memberOf $devices) from entry-point FMSensorEvents
    not Activation(ruleSpec == $r, cause == $e)
    // no activation within past triggerEvery seconds for same device
    not Activation(
        ruleSpec == $r, 
        deviceId == $e.deviceId, 
        start.time > ($e.start.time - ($r.triggerEvery * 1000))
    )
then
    insert(new Activation($r, $e));
end
```